# Faulty Domain disabled error message

Tags: email-server

We were using hMailserver for 2 different domains. One of which we recently moved over to gmail, the other we left in place.

Within hMailServer we simply marked the moved domain as "disabled" by unchecking the "enable" box on the General tab for the domain.  Basically we need to preserve the old stuff for various reasons.

However, when I send an email from the other domain to the moved one, hMailServer responds with a `550: Domain is Disabled` error message.

My question is: How do I get hMailServer to go ahead and send to that moved domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've disabled the domain you haven't told hMailServer not to treat it as authoritative, so it will either try to deliver the message to the local copy of the account, or reject as you've found since the domain is disabled.

Presumably the reason for wanting to keep is listed is to maintain the accounts you have configured within that domain? Other than simply delete the domain, and all the accounts within it, the only option I can think of would be to rename the domain, eg change mydomain.com to mydomain.com.foo or something. Then mydomain.com will no longer be considered to be local, and your server will send the email outbound as required, but all the mailboxes and settings will remain as before. Note, once you rename the domain in hMailServer all of the accounts will also have their details changed. So if you needed to connect to the old POP3/IMAP mailbox later on you'd need to adjust the username you were connecting with (assuming that domain isn't configured as your default domain, in which case you'd want to update that as well obviously).

Comment: Sounds like this would work just fine.  I'll give it a go.  Yes - we have a number of old accounts that were not migrated to the new server (people not here) however I need to maintain those old emails *just in case*.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used hMailServer but my guess is that even though that domain is disabled, hMailServer is still authoritative for it. So it expects to manage email for that domain but because it's disabled refuses to actually accept email for that domain.

My assumption is that the logic is that you may want to temporarily disable mail flow for a particular domain without necessarily removing the domain.

So to get hMailServer to send to the moved domain you'll probably need to remove/delete that domain from hMailServer.